# Move multiple folders with exact name to it's own parent folder

Tags: batch-file, command-line, move, subdirectory

I have file structure like this:

> ```
> folder
> +---a
> |   \---b
> |       \---foo bar
> +---c
> |   \---d
> |       \---foo bar
> +---.
> \---.
> ```

I want to move `foo bar` to it's own parent folder, using a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

I tried this in [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) but it said:

> ```
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
> ```

```dos
cd "path to folder"
for /r %x in (foo bar) do move "%x" ".."
```

**Edit**

I've changed my command to this:

```dos
for /r %x in ("foo bar") do move "%x" "%~px.."
```

But now it gives an error, because there is space between foo and bar here: `("foo bar")`, what should I do? use `foo?bar` instead of `"foo bar"` maybe?

**Edit 2**

my final command:

```dos
for /d /r %x in ("?oo bar") do if "%~nx"=="foo bar" move "%x" "%~px.."
```

I didn't use `(*)` because it drastically increases the command execution time if you have hundreds of folders since it has to check every folder for it's name.

Thanks everyone for their help

Comment: for /r %x in ("foo bar") do move "%x" "%~px.." i've changed my command to this but now it gives error because there is quotation here: ("foo bar") what should i do? use foo?bar instead of "foo bar" maybe?

Comment: You cannot have two directories named `foo bar` in the same directory, `folder`. Can you also please confirm that my heavy edit if your question has maintained the structure you intended to show us?

Comment: As already pointed out you are going to have a collision if you try to move both of the folders up one level to the same level. But you also learned a small quirk with the `FOR /R` command.  If you didn't have the collision you could do something like this: `for /D /r %G IN ("foo ba?") do if /i "%~nxG"=="foo bar" move "%G" ..`

Comment: Start with `for /r %x in ("foo bar*") do @ECHO move "%x" "%~px.."` - nothe that you _must_ use a wildcard in `for /r …` loop. Moreover, use `ECHO move …` when debugging.

Comment: @Compo no it's wrong structure. b is in the a folder and d is in the c folder.

Comment: @Squashman edited structure was wrong there is no collision. your approach seems more reasonable than mine: for /d /r %x in (foo?bar) do move "%x" "%~px.." i'm glad there was no footbar folder :D do you know why ("foo bar") doesn't work?

Comment: @JosefZ you forgot /d. i'm sure i've used for /r loop without wildcards in the past but weirdly enough ("foo bar") doesn't work and ("foobar") works. that space is the problem

Comment: @Squashman also your command moves all of the files to parent folder of the command line directory. so it should be move "%G" "%~pG.."

Comment: @AnilD, I have corrected your tree structure accordingly.

Comment: I had files in my test folder and when the folder was moved the files stayed in the foo bar folder so I am not sure how you are getting different results.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying now. That is because you changed your folder structure.  You didn't have them nested that far down. Next time use the output of the `TREE` command to show that correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included the below examples, to not use recursion, and use `RoboCopy` for the moving action. `RoboCopy` has the benefit of being able to merge directories, and overwrite/or otherwise, *(depending upon the options you choose)*, should there be any collisions.

If you're only moving directories with a specific name, e.g. `foo bar` then the following [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) may help:

```dos
(PushD "folder"&&(For /D %G In (*)Do @For /D %H In ("%G\*") Do @RoboCopy "%H\foo bar" "%G\foo bar" /E /Move)&PopD)>NUL 2>&1
```

If you're moving all directories, regardless of their names, from three levels below `folder` up one level then perhaps this will suffice.

```dos
(PushD "folder"&&(For /D %G In (*)Do @For /D %H In ("%G\*") Do @For /D %I In ("%H\*")Do @RoboCopy "%I" "%G\%~nxI" /E /Move)&PopD)>NUL 2>&1
```

*Please note that no checks have been included to determine whether the second level directories, which had contained your targets are now empty. If they are, and you wish to remove them, you'll need to expand the command lines, or add new ones as needed.*

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r /d %A in (*) do if /i "%~nxA" == "foo bar" move /y "%~A" "%~dpA.."
```

Using `*` as `(set)`. If you view `for /?`, you may see:

> (set) Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.

So, `(set)` is files, not folders.

Ideally, use a letter for the `for` variable that is not a modifier letter. `x` represents the extension modifier.

`%~nxA` will be the current folder name and check if is `foo bar`.

If `move` fails if `foo bar` already exist, then an access is denied to warn of it's existence.

If used in a batch-file, double up the `%` characters to `%%`.

Alternate loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /s /a:d "*foo bar"') do if /i "%~nxA" == "foo bar" move /y "%~A" "%~dpA.."
```

which gets the paths before the loop begins to avoid multiple moves of the same folder.

Comment: `(set)` is also folders. `/d` just specifies to match against folders if wildcards are used. so it's not needed when there is no wildcards. other than that thanks for the `x` tip

Comment: I should warn that `for /r` iterates and that the same moved folder may again be moved again due to the iteration done in real time. So a `for /f` with use of `dir` can cache the paths before starting the loop which may help avoid moves of the same folder. Added the alternative to the answer.